# cannot resolve constructor 'FirebaseListAdapter'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

It says unable to resolve constructor firebaseListAdapter.
This is my MainActivity. 
Error on line:

> listAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(this, chat.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, mRef)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private DatabaseReference mRef;
 private FirebaseListAdapter < chat > listAdapter;
 ListView lv;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);


  mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

  listAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter < chat > (this, chat.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, mRef) {
   @Override
   protected void populateView(View view, chat chatMessage, int position) {
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(chatMessage.getName());
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(chatMessage.getMsg());
   }
  };
  lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
 }
}
```

This is my Chat.class

```
public class chat {
 String name, msg;

 public chat() {}

 public chat(String name, String msg) {
  this.name = name;
  this.msg = msg;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public String getMsg() {
  return msg;
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you using firebase 3.x?

Comment: yes, I am using the upgraded version of firebase

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. It was just a small glitch.
I had imported;

```
com.firebase.ui.FirebaseListAdapter
```

The correct import package should be;

```
com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter
```

That's it and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-ui:0.1.0'
```

and then

```
import com.firebase.ui.FirebaseListAdapter;
```